# Is it possible to set allowed-integers in a slot with a variable?

Tags: clips

I want to constrain my allowed integers in a slot with a multifieldvariable.

So instead of:

```
CLIPS> (deftemplate foo (slot constr-integers (allowed-integers 1 3 4 7)))
```

I wanted do do something like this:

```
CLIPS> (bind ?multifieldvariable (create$ 1 3 4 7))
(1 3 4 7)
CLIPS> (deftemplate bar (slot constr-integers (allowed-integers ?multifieldvariable)))

[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for allowed-integers attribute.

ERROR:
(deftemplate MAIN::bar
   (slot constr-integers (allowed-integers ?multifieldvariable
```

I know how to work around this issue, but maybe there is a way to do it in a more elegant way.

Best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do it by dynamically creating the deftemplate with a build function call:

```
CLIPS> (bind ?multifieldvariable (create$ 1 3 4 7))
(1 3 4 7)
CLIPS> 
(build (str-cat "(deftemplate bar (slot constr-integers (allowed-integers " 
                 (implode$ ?multifieldvariable)
                ")))"))
TRUE
CLIPS> (ppdeftemplate bar)
(deftemplate MAIN::bar
   (slot constr-integers (allowed-integers 1 3 4 7)))
CLIPS>
```